# TableView Cell Separator Line Not Extending Across the Entire Cell

Tags: swift, interface-builder, xcode6

I am working on a new project and have used a storyboard for the UI.  All of my tableViews have an issue with the line separator.  The picture below shows two lines.  The first is a blue one which was set in the attributes inspector.  The second one is black and was added with an imageView that I placed in the cell.  The line does extend to the right side of the cell but not the left.  Any ideas?

[image: Blue separator line does not extend all the way to the left side of the cell.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first set table view
1.set separatorInset of tableview instance to UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
second set cell
1.set preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins of cell (instance) to NO
2.set layoutMargins of cell to UIEdgeInsetsZero
3.saet separatorInset of cell to UIEdgeInsetsZero

Hope to help you

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your cell property called preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins is set to false (default)

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
```

Then you just have to set your cell layoutMargins to zero

```
cell.layoutMargins = .zero
```

---

You need also to select you cell separator, select custom and change left value from 15 to 0

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it did not resolve the issue.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to just follow the two visual steps in the size inspector and not the programmatic code and it fixed my issue